# Is there a way to update the graphics in opengl when a window is being moved?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am working on an application in java and I would like to know if it is possible to keep updating the graphics in LWJGL3 even when the window is being moved or resized?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this source may help. [Link](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/glfw/Multithreaded.java)

I believe that your problem is that GLFW methods like glfwWindowShouldClose() block while the window is being changed. Therefore, if you use that code to split the rendering into it's own thread, you should be able to render even while the window is resizing.

**Note:** I have not tested that code myself, but based on who wrote it I am confident that it works.